# Handling pagination in lxml

Tags: python, html, pagination, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to mirror a ruby scraper that I wrote but for a python only environment. I've decided to use lxml and requests to get this done. My problem is pagination:

```
base_url = "http://example.com/something/?page=%s"  
for url in [base_url % i for i in xrange(10)]:  
    r = requests.get(url)
```

I'm new to python and this library so I'm not sure the best way to perform the equivalent ruby code:

```
last_pg = (page.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'b-tabs-utility')]").text.split('of ')[-1].split(' Results')[0].to_f / 60).ceil
puts "Current Index: #{last_pg}"
for pg_number in 1..last_pg do
  puts "Getting links on page #{pg_number}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the number of results by splitting the `b-tabs-utility` div into spaces and getting element before last:

```
base_url = "http://example.com/something/?page=%d" 
results_per_page = 60

div = page.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'b-tabs-utility')]")[0].text
last_pg = int(div.split()[-2]) / results_per_page
for i in xrange(last_pg):
    r = requests.get(base_url % i)
```

I'm [assuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981386/capybara-dsl-screen-scraper-working-on-a-single-page-but-fails-without-error-aft) the `div` text is in the following format, example: `... of 642 Results`