# Scraping paginated sites and appending output in Python

Tags: python, pagination, web-scraping, lxml, python-requests

I have a simple scraping task that I would like to ***improve the pagination efficiency*** of, and ***append lists*** so that I may **output the results of scraping** to a common/single file.

The current task is scraping municipal laws for the city of São Paulo, iterating over the first 10 pages. I would like to find a way to determine the total number of pages for pagination, and have the script automatically cycle through all pages, similar in spirit to this: [Handling pagination in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318476/handling-pagination-in-lxml).

The xpaths for the pagination links are too poorly defined at the moment for me to understand how to do this effectively. For instance, on the [first](http://www.leismunicipais.com.br/legislacao-municipal/5298/leis-de-sao-paulo?q=&page=1&types=o) or [last page](http://www.leismunicipais.com.br/legislacao-municipal/5298/leis-de-sao-paulo?q=&page=1608&types=o) (1 or 1608), there are only three li nodes, while on page [page 1605](http://www.leismunicipais.com.br/legislacao-municipal/5298/leis-de-sao-paulo?q=&page=1605&types=o) there are 6 nodes.

> /html/body/div/section/ul[2]/li/a

***How may I efficiently account for this pagination***; making the determination of pages in an automated way rather than manually, and how can I properly specify the xpaths to cycle through all the appropriate pages, without duplicates?

The existing code is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests  
from lxml import html

base_url = "http://www.leismunicipais.com.br/legislacao-municipal/5298/leis-de-sao-paulo?q=&page=%d&types=o" 
for url in [base_url % i for i in xrange(10)]:
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    #This will create a list of titles:
    titles = tree.xpath('/html/body/div/section/ul/li/a/strong/text()')
    #This will create a list of descriptions:
    desc = tree.xpath('/html/body/div/section/ul/li/a/text()')
    #This will create a list of URLs
    url = tree.xpath('/html/body/div/section/ul/li/a/@href')

    print 'Titles: ', titles
    print 'Description: ', desc
    print 'URL: ', url
```

Secondarily, ***how can I compile/append these results and write them out to JSON, SQL, etc?*** I prefer JSON due to familiarity, but am rather ambivalent about how to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to examine the data layout of your page/site. Each site is different. Look for 'pagination' or 'next' or some slider. Extract the details/count and use that in your loop.
2. import json library. You have a json dump function...

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't understand your problem properly, this code will help invigorate your new attempt. The code is compatible with python 3 and later version.

```
import requests  
from lxml import html

result = {}
base_url = "https://leismunicipais.com.br/legislacao-municipal/5298/leis-de-sao-paulo?q=&page={0}&types=28&types=5" 
for url in [base_url .format(i) for i in range(1,3)]:
    tree = html.fromstring(requests.get(url).text)
    for title in tree.cssselect(".item-result"):
        try:
            name = ' '.join(title.cssselect(".title a")[0].text.split())
        except Exception:
            name = ""

        try:
            url = ' '.join(title.cssselect(".domain")[0].text.split())
        except Exception:
            url = ""
        result[name] = url

print(result)
```

Partial output:

```
{'Decreto 57998/2017': 'http://leismunicipa.is', 'Decreto 58009/2017': 'http://leismunicipa.is'}
```